# Send a custom email with additional account fields values on save in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, email-notifications

On the basis of the plugin “Advanced Custom Fields” additional fields were created for the personal account of WooCommerce users. Using the second "ACF for WooCommerce" plugin, I placed these fields on the edit-account page.

If the user has filled in the fields or edited them, the administrator will receive an email with the values of these fields. The following code is responsible for notifications:

```
if (!class_exists('WooCommerceNotifyChanges')) {

    class WooCommerceNotifyChanges {

        function __construct() {                        
            add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array($this, 'woocommerce_send_notification'), 15, 1);
        }

        function woocommerce_send_notification($user_id) {
            $body = '';
            $to = 'info@domain.com'; 
            $subject = 'Edit profile data';

            update_meta_cache('user', $user_id); // delete cache   

            $user = new WP_User($user_id);
            $user_name = $user->user_login;

            $body .= '<table>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>'.__("Profile"). '</td></tr>';                        
            $body .= '<tr><td>Login: </td><td>'.$user_name. '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>First Name: </td><td>'.$user->billing_first_name. '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>Last Name: </td><td>'.$user->billing_last_name. '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>'.get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b4640119354c', $single=true). '</td></tr>'; //text field
            $body .= '<tr><td>Age: </td><td>'.get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b462d304b101', $single=true). '</td></tr>'; //text field
            $body .= '<tr><td>Family: </td><td>'.get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b4bd7d9f0031', $single=true). '</td></tr>'; // selector                       
            $body .= '<tr><td>What style do you prefer? </td><td>'.get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b47917a378ed', $single=true). '</td></tr>'; // checkbox                      

            $body .= '</table>';

            //set content type as HTML
            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

            //send email
            if (wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                //echo 'email sent';
            } else {
                //echo 'email NOT sent';                
            }
            //exit();
        }
    }
    new WooCommerceNotifyChanges();
}
```

#### Here two errors occur:

1. When a user edits these fields, old, apparently cached data is sent to the administrator email. When you re-send without editing, you will receive the correct field data.

   I put a line of code:

   ```
   update_meta_cache('user', $user_id);
   ```

   But it does not work, the old data is still coming. Apparently, I did something wrong.
2. The data of all fields are correctly stored in the database and also correctly displayed in an email to the administrator. The problem with checkboxes.

   In this case, the "What style do you prefer?" three checkboxes "Classic", "Casual" and "Sport" are displayed. The user selected the "Casual" checkbox. The value of this field is correctly stored in the database.

   But in the email to the administrator, instead of this value, only the word “Array” comes.

Tell me how to fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No one can help? ((

Comment: I don't know woocommerce, but maybe this can help. Are you sure woocommerce_send_notification() executes AFTER the user data is saved? I assume not according to your story. 
How does the array holding the 'style' look likes? Maybe it helps printing it as array in the mail: `print_r(get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b47917a378ed', $single=true), true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update 1 - Solving the plugin problems.

**1) Caching issue:** I finally found the problem in "ACF for WooCommerce" plugin source code.

> You need to use a **higher priority value** as the plugin **uses a priority of 100**

So your in your code you will replace (in the constructor):

```
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array($this, 'woocommerce_send_notification'), 15, 1);
```

by a priority value of **`150`** *(or more)* for example:

```
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array($this, 'woocommerce_send_notification'), 150, 1);
```

It should solve definitively your fake "caching" issue *(Thanks to Kashalo)*.

---

**2) The checkboxes fields** for "What style do you prefer?".

You need to convert the array to a string with coma separated values…

Use the following:

```
function woocommerce_send_notification($user_id) {
    // Recipient
    $to = 'info@domain.com'; 
    
    $subject = 'Edit profile data';

    $user =      new WP_User($user_id);
    $user_name = $user->user_login;
    
    $phone  = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'field_5b4640119354c', true ); // Phone - text field
    $age    = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'field_5b462d304b101', true ); // Age- text field
    $family = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'field_5b4bd7d9f0031', true ); // Family - select field 
    $fstyle = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'field_5b47917a378ed', true ); // Favorited styles - Multiple Checkboxes 

     // Convert the array to a coma separated list (Favorited styles)
    $fstyle = implode( ', ',  $fstyle ); 
    
    // Body output
    $body = '<h3>'. __("Profile") .'</h3>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Login: </td><td>'.      $user->user_login         .'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name: </td><td>'. $user->billing_first_name .'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name: </td><td>'.  $user->billing_last_name  .'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phone: </td><td>'.      $phone                    .'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Age: </td><td>'.        $age                      .'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Family: </td><td>'.     $family                   .'</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>What style do you prefer? </td><td>'. $fstyle     .'</td></tr> 
    </table>';

    //set content type as HTML
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

    //send email
    $sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
```

---

#### Original answer:

> Testing and trying to reproduce your issue **is not possible** within the provided information and code in this question, as nobody can guess your ACF settings and related context.
>
> **Using Advanced Custom fields is not a good idea** for that, when doing multiple customizations. You are loosing so much time, trying to find out what is wrong since a while.
>
> **The best way is to hand code custom fields** without using a plugin as developers do.

In the following code I am:

1. Adding and displaying the additional fields in the CLASS itself **without ACF**,
2. Validating the fields data,
3. Saving the data and **sending the email notification with the correct data** (without any cache problem),
4. displaying those additional fields in Admin user edit pages under woocommerce billing section.

> Now as you dont give the option values for the **"Family"** select field and for the **"Preferred style"** checkboxes, you will have to set the desired values in the settings section in each array.
>
> **When testing this code you will have to disable the related ACF fields.**

The complete functional code *(without ACF)*:

```
if ( ! class_exists('WC_Additional_Account_fields') ) {

    class WC_Additional_Account_fields {
        // 1. Constructor
        function __construct() {

            ## A. Settings

            // The text domain
            $this->text_domain    = 'aafields';

            // The current user WP_User object
            $this->user           = wp_get_current_user();

            // The Admin email
            $this->admin_email    = get_option('admin_email');

            // The array of options for "Family" and "preferred style"
            $this->fields_options = array(
                // FAMILY available options array
                'family' => array(
                    __("No childs", $this->text_domain ),
                    __("One child", $this->text_domain ),
                    __("2 childs", $this->text_domain ),
                    __("3 or more childs", $this->text_domain ),
                ),
                // PREFERRED STYLE available options array
                'preferred_styles' => array(
                    __("Style 1", $this->text_domain ),
                    __("Style 2", $this->text_domain ),
                    __("Style 3", $this->text_domain ),
                    __("Style 4", $this->text_domain ),
                ),
            );

            ## B. Hooking functions

            add_action('woocommerce_edit_account_form', array($this, 'add_other_fields_in_edit_account_form') );
            add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array($this, 'save_other_fields_in_edit_account_form'), 15, 1);
            add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', array($this, 'validate_other_fields_in_edit_account_form'), 15, 1 );
            add_filter('woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', array($this, 'add_customer_meta_fields_to_admin_user_list'), 15, 1 );
        }


        // 1. Displaying additional account fields (+ jQuery script to handle checkboxes as radio buttons)
        public function add_other_fields_in_edit_account_form() {
            $text_domain = $this->text_domain;
            $user        = $this->user;
            $options     = $this->fields_options;

            $phone  = isset($user->phone) ? $user->phone : '';
            $age    = isset($user->billing_age) ? $user->billing_age : '';
            $family = isset($user->billing_family) ? $user->billing_family : '';
            $pstyle = isset($user->billing_pref_style) ? $user->billing_pref_style : '';

            // Inline styles
            ?>
            <style>
                #billing_pref_style_field span.label {padding:0 12px 0 6px;}
                div.clear {clear:both;margin-bottom:1.4em;}
            </style>
            <?php

            // Fields 1 and 2
            ?>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
                <label for="phone"><?php _e( "Phone number", $text_domain ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
                <label for="billing_age"><?php _e( "Age", $text_domain ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="billing_age" id="billing_age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" />
            </p>
            <?php

            // Fields 3 and 4 (Select field + Grouped checkboxes)
            ?>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-first">
                <label for="billing_family"><?php _e( "Family", $text_domain ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <select id="billing_family" class="woocommerce-Select woocommerce-Select--option select" name="billing_family">
                    <option value=""><?php _e( "Select a value", $text_domain ); ?></option>
                    <?php
                        foreach( $options['family'] as $option ) :
                            $selected = ( $family == $option ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                            echo '<option value="' . $option . '"' . $selected . '>' . $option . '</option>';
                        endforeach;
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p id="billing_pref_style_field" class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
                <label for="preferred_styles"><?php _e( "What style do you prefer? ", $text_domain ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <?php
                        foreach( $options['preferred_styles'] as $key => $option ) :
                            $checked = $pstyle == $option ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
                            echo '<span><input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--checkbox input-checkbox" name="pref_style" value="' . $option . '"' . $checked . '><span class="label">' . $option . '</span></span>';
                        endforeach;
                    ?>
                </select>
                <?php $value = ! empty($pstyle) ? $pstyle : $options['preferred_styles'][0];
                // Hidden field that catch the active checkbox value ?>
                <input type="hidden"  name="billing_pref_style" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php

            // jQuery code: Enabling grouped checkboxes and passing the chosen value to the hidden field
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){
                var a = '#billing_pref_style_field',        b = a+' input[type="checkbox"]',
                    c = a+' input[type="hidden"]';

                $(b+'[value="'+$(c).val()+'"]').attr('checked', true);
                $(b).click( function(){
                    var d = $(this).val();
                    $(c).val(d);
                    $(b).each( function( i, v ) {
                        if( d != $(v).val() ){
                            $(v).prop('checked', false);
                        } else {
                            $(v).prop('checked', true);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>
            <?php
        }

        // 2. Additional account fields validation
        public function validate_other_fields_in_edit_account_form( $args ){
            if ( isset($_POST['phone']) && empty($_POST['phone']) )
                $args->add( 'error', __( 'Please fill in the "Phone" field', 'woocommerce' ),'');

            if ( isset($_POST['billing_age']) && empty($_POST['billing_age']) )
                $args->add( 'error', __( 'Please fill in the "Age" field', 'woocommerce' ),'');

            if ( isset($_POST['billing_family']) && empty($_POST['billing_family']) )
                $args->add( 'error', __( 'Please choose a value for the "Family" field', 'woocommerce' ),'');

            if ( isset($_POST['billing_pref_style']) && empty($_POST['billing_pref_style']) )
                $args->add( 'error', __( 'Please choose a "Preferred style"', 'woocommerce' ),'');
        }

        // 3. Save custom additional fields value + Send custom email
        public function save_other_fields_in_edit_account_form( $user_id ) {
            $text_domain = $this->text_domain;
            $send_notification = false;

            if( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ){
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phone'] ) );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phone'] ) );
                if( ! empty( $_POST['phone'] ) )
                    $send_notification = true;
            }

            // For Favorite color 2
            if( isset( $_POST['billing_age'] ) ){
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_age', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_age'] ) );
                if( ! empty( $_POST['billing_age'] ) )
                    $send_notification = true;
            }

            // For Billing email (added related to your comment)
            if( isset( $_POST['billing_family'] ) ){
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_family', esc_attr( $_POST['billing_family'] ) );
                if( ! empty( $_POST['billing_family'] ) )
                    $send_notification = true;
            }

            // For Billing email (added related to your comment)
            if( isset( $_POST['billing_pref_style'] ) ){
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_pref_style', esc_attr( $_POST['billing_pref_style'] ) );
                if( ! empty( $_POST['billing_pref_style'] ) )
                    $send_notification = true;
            }

            if( $send_notification ){
                $user = new WP_User($user_id);

                $to = $this->admin_email;
                $subject = __('Edited profile data for: ') . $user->billing_first_name . ' ' . $user->billing_last_name;

                $body = '<h3>' . __("Profile", $text_domain ) . '</h3>
                <table>
                <tr><th align="left">' . __("Login:", $text_domain ) . '</th><td>'. $user->user_login . '</td></tr>
                <tr><th align="left">' . __("First Name:", $text_domain ) . ' </th><td>' . $user->billing_first_name . '</td></tr>
                <tr><th align="left">' . __("Last Name:", $text_domain ) . ' </th><td>' . $user->billing_last_name . '</td></tr>
                <tr><th align="left">' . __("Phone:", $text_domain ) . ' </th><td>' . $user->phone . '</td></tr>
                <tr><th align="left">' . __("Age:", $text_domain ) . ' </th><td>' . $user->billing_age . '</td></tr>
                <tr><th align="left">' . __("Family:", $text_domain ) . ' </th><td>' . $user->billing_family . '</td></tr>
                <tr><th align="left">' . __("Preferred style", $text_domain ) . ' </th><td>' . $user->billing_pref_style . '</td></tr>
                </table>';

                //set content type as HTML
                $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

                //send email
                wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
            }
        }

        // 4. Add the additional fields in admin user list in the billing section
        public function add_customer_meta_fields_to_admin_user_list( $args ) {
            $domain  = $this->text_domain;
            $options = $this->fields_options;

            // Age
            $args['billing']['fields']['billing_age'] = array(
                'label'       => __( "Age", $text_domain ),
                'description' => '',
            );

            // Family
            $args['billing']['fields']['billing_family'] = array(
                'label'       => __( 'Family', 'woocommerce' ),
                'description' => '',
                'type'        => 'select',
                'options'     => array( '' => __( 'Select a value', $domain ) ) + array_combine($options['family'], $options['family']),
            );

            // Preferred styles
            $args['billing']['fields']['billing_pref_style'] = array(
                'label'       => __( 'Preferred styles', 'woocommerce' ),
                'description' => '',
                'type'        => 'select',
                'options'     => array( '' => __( 'Select a value', $domain ) ) + array_combine($options['preferred_styles'], $options['prefered_styles']),
            );

            return $args;
        }
    }
    new WC_Additional_Account_fields();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> The phone field updates both **user phone** and **user billing phone** at the same time.

---

**The additional fields on My Account > Account details section:**

[image]

---

**The Fields validation:**

[image]

---

**The email notification *(on "Save changes")* filled with the fresh saved data:**

[image]

---

**And finally the displayed fields in the Admin users pages under the billing section:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! How do I understand that in order to test this code, I need to completely deactivate the ACF plugin? If I want to create new custom fields, do I need to make them similar to yours?

Comment: There may be a problem that these fields will be displayed during user registration. Therefore, I used the “ACF for Woocommerce” plugin and put these fields in “Edit Account Form Start”, then they were not shown during registration.

Comment: When I put your code in the functions.php file, I had duplicate additional fields after the email and after the "password change".

Comment: It's something complicated and I have work to do… So I started but not finished yet… Be patient.

Comment: Ok. I'll wait. Thanks!

Comment: @Dmitry Finaly I have found The problem in the plugin source code… So I have the 2 answers to your actual code problems…

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Everything is working!